# How to count 2 fields with different conditions for each count in HQL

Tags: database, hibernate, hql

I have a problem writing HQL.
The problem is that I want something like this to be transferred to HQL

```
 select 
   tb.aca_year, 
   (case when tw.isfulltime = 1 then count(te) end) as fulltime,
   (case when tw.isfulltime = 0 then count(te) end) as parttime
 from timetable tb, teacher te, teacherworktype tw 
  where .............
  group by tb.aca_year
 ................
```

any suggestion please?

Best Regards,

Comment: You can't write HQL without knowing the class model. So tell us something about your classes...

Comment: Thank for concerning my question. However, those classes are very long. could you please base on my question to help me?

Comment: I'm confused. How can `case when tw.isfulltime` actually work when it is neither in an aggregate function nor is `tw.isfulltime` in the group by clause ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select tb.aca_year, 
    sum(case when tw.isfulltime = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as fulltime, 
    sum(case when tw.isfulltime = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as parttime
from timetable tb, teacher te, teacherworktype tw 
where ............. 
group by tb.aca_year ................
```